# Insert image into Access from PHP

Tags: php, image, ms-access, pdo

I need to insert images into an Access Database.
I know I should avoid saving images and binary files to the database.

I tried:

```
$data = file_get_contents("teste.jpg");
```

And save it directly with PDO but it didn't work. I tried to convert the result to base64 but it also didn't work.

The type of the field is BLOB and I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

I did this  coincidentally yesterday. This is what I had done:

```
    if($request['file'] != null) {
        $file = $request['file'];
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $imageType = pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    } else {
        $file = null;
        $imageType = null;
    }
    Project::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'content' => $request['content'],
        'image' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($file)),
        'image_type' => $imageType,
    ]);
```

I think it's already clear enough to understand my code. If it isn't, just ask!

Comment: No, it didnt work for me... that i retry and say that in my question

Comment: Ah ok could you maybe post more code, so that I can help you? I want to see your form and how you retrieve data from the form. Also important to mention my image column has a datatype of mediumtext in my database.